# Updating multiple columns from multiple rows in a separate table

Tags: sql, sql-update, ssms

I’m trying to update multiple columns in from multiple rows from a different table in my DB - using TSQL
Here is my Update

```
UPDATE pm
    SET [COL1] = CASE WHEN p.MID=’Hi’ THEN 1 ELSE [COL1] END,
    SET [COL2] = CASE WHEN p.MID=’Bye’ THEN 1 ELSE [COL2] END
FROM 
    Papers p
    INNER JOIN PaperMeasures pm ON pm.PaperID=p.PaperID
```

Now the Papers table has multiple rows of the same info – except for the MID column. One row could read “Hi” while the other row could read “Bye” like so

```
PaperID | MID | PaperName …
-------------------------------------
1       | Hi  | PaperName1
-------------------------------------
1       | Bye | PaperName1
```

While in the column I want to update there is only one row with the designated PaperID that I want to update the multiple columns for.  It should look like the below

```
PaperID | Hi | Bye …
-------------------------------------
1       | 1  | 1
```

So far it looks like for the instances above – My PM table only gets to check off **one** of the columns (Bye) rather than both (Hi and Bye) 
Not sure how I can make it capture both.

Comment: Are you sure you're using MySQL and not SQL-Server? MySQL doesn't use brackets around column names like that.

Comment: Yep I'm using SQL-Server

Comment: Just noticed one of my tags said mysql - just removed